# Linux user can't access mergerfs directory that he already has permissions

Tags: permissions

I use proxmox on top of Debian 12 (bookworm).

As root user I set the owner for the directory '/data' to berdux:berdux and even set permissions to 777.

Then I mount 4 disks to this folder with mergerfs (again user berdux has full access and permissions to these ZFS mounts).

```
mergerfs -o cache.files=partial,dropcacheonclose=true,category.create=mfs /D2TBa/2TBa:/D2TBb/2TBb:/D4TBa/4TBa:/D4TBb/4TBb /data
```

Then I change to user berdux (su berdux) and I lose access to said folder.

What i see with ls -l from root:

`drwxrwxrwx   3 berdux berdux     3 Sep 14 10:56 data`

And then with ls -l from user berdux:

`d?????????   ? ?      ?          ?            ? data`

I have tried to run the mergerfs command from the user berdux with sudo and I tried puting it on fstab (and i have rebooted several times) but nothing changes.

I also want to share this folder with samba, and it isn't possible while the user doesn't have access to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a bug. The proper arguments are not being used. IE... `allow_other`. You need to use the documents from the version being used. Newer releases set the value automatically. See the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, there must have been a bug in the default version of mergerfs in debian repository (2.33.5)

I installed manually the latest (2.37.1) and it worked.